# how to enable drag of embed video object in browser (ie. YouTube videos)

Tags: javascript, browser, drag-and-drop, embed, html5-video

How can I enable dragging of an `<embed>` object on a webpage (with javascript)? Normally, when I select some text or an image on a webpage, I am able to drag it around, and I want to do the same for the  object.

Specifically, I want to be able to drag a YouTube video. I'm not concerned about dropping for now, and also I don't want to use jQuery UI if at all possible. The YouTube embed looks like this

`<embed id="movie_player" ... type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />`

I'm writing a browser extension (for Chrome), so I have full access to the DOM and the browser.

Comment: jQuery UI `draggable()` might be of use here. Edi: no luck so far: http://jsfiddle.net/SbxnF/.

Comment: any way to do it without jQuery UI? also it would be awesome if you could see a little semi-transparent preview of what you're dragging, just like when you drag an image, link or selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jQuery is the best here, it is also javascript and all you do is embed it to your website. And if you want a semi-transparent effect to view that you are dragging, I think you can add an event for a dragging handle. Use onMouseDown and onMouseUp. For example, this div is handle your youtube:
The CSS for transparent is:

`opacity: .7; filter:Alpha(Opacity=70);` whereby 0.7 and 70 is the opacity percent of element!

[Example]:

`<div onMouseDown="this.style.opacity='0.7'; this.style.filter='Alpha(Opacity=70)';" onMouseUp="this.style.opacity='1.0'; this.style.filter='Alpha(Opacity=100)';"><br><embed something here></embed></div>`.

Ok, If you change your mind somehow and you want to use jQuery, give it a try, I promise it is extremely easy!

First of all, embed this into your website:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".drag").draggable();});</script>`

Secondly, give anything you want to drag a class "drag", in this case:

`<div class="drag">YOUR YOUTUBE VIDEO EMBED HERE</div>`

Use it together with the semi-transparent effect, I think that all you need, and I hope this help.

xx3004,

Comment: actually using jQuery is fine, but I'm trying to avoid adding jQuery UI. I'm just curious as to how the browser allows dragging of images, selections, and links, but not of <embed>s. Isn't there some way make the browser treat the embed the same way as an image? I just find jQuery UI too heavyweight, even just the draggable part.

Comment: I put some more time into using jquery ui draggable, and now it's actually working out so far. Using the start and stop events of the draggable component was useful.

Comment: @mark: I also have an embed tag and want to do drag and drop for it, and I don't want to use jQuery UI. Have you figured out how to make it work without jQuery UI?